# replace www with any word and it resolves to the website instead of giving a 404 error

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, subdomain

I have a website that when you type in any word in the subdomain part of the URL it resolves to the domain. For instance monkey.mysite.com resolves the same as www.mysite.com or mysite.com would. No matter what page you are on it will still resolve the URL. It is a Wordpress site and has an SSL certificate. It was also recently infected with a virus. Can someone explain to me what could cause this?

Here is the rewrite rule in the .htaccess file:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com$
    RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mysite\.com" [R=301,L]
```

There is not a subdomain associated with this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is not related to the rewrite rules in Apache but rather to your DNS settings. If the `subdomain.mysite.com` does not have a DNS record, the proper response in your browser would be "Server not found" (since the IP could not be resolved)  rather then HTTP 404 error (i.e. page not found).

Anyway, you can check the response given by your DNS server on Mac/Linux with,

```
dig subdomain.mysite.com
```

which should return not found if that subdomain indeed does not exist.
Alternatively, there are some tools to do this [online](http://dig-nslookup.nmonitoring.com/dns-dig-nslookup.html).

Comment: Thank you this pointed me in the right direction. I found that the DNS settings had a wildcard subdomain set.